# Maven doesn't install embedded dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have project `A` and `B`.

And project `A` has project `B`'s dependency in `pom.xml`.

Project `A` is Spring boot application and project `B` is maven project.

- project `A`'s pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifact>b</artifact>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-external</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <file>${basedir}/lib/b-1.0.0.jar</file>
                <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
                <artifactId>b</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

- project B's pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.15.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I compile project `A`, it works.

But when I execute it, `noclassdeffounderror` occurs with `jsoup` in project `B` when creating beans.

I've found project `A` doesn't add project `B`'s dependencies.

How can I install project `B`'s dependency without add dependency in project `A`'s `pom.xml`?

Comment: just use `mvn install` on project B (adding it to the repo) and making project B a normal dependency of project A (without install-external/process-resources)?

Comment: A spring boot jar is a fat jar and cannot be used as a dependency (unless you generate a different artifact). Why isn't it just a regular dependency, why messing around with the install plugin?

Comment: @M.Deinum Project ```B``` isn't spring boot jar. Just maven project.

Comment: If it is just a maven project then still why the messing around with the install plugin? That should be just a dependency and if the dependencies are properly defined in its pom.xml you will automatically get them. Installing it manually will overwrite the pom generated by maven when generating the jar and as such doesn't include anything. So basically you are working against maven yourself here.

Comment: I don't have repositories like Nexus. So I needed to add my library into spring boot application.